# Can't get the file of input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I can't get the file of `<input type="file">`.

In the code below, I create a ui dialog and have two inputs. One of them is text and the other is a file input / upload.

I can get the text value but can't get the file input.

```js
var $container = $(document.body);
var j = '<div class="form-group fileupload">'
      +      '<label>' + ' Döküman Adı Girin :' + '</label>'
      +      '<input type="text" id="mediatitle" placeholder="Döküman Adı" class="form-control"></br>'
      +      '<label>' + 'File Yükle' + '</label>'
      +      '<input id="FileUpload" type="file"/>'
      + '</div>',
    k = '<button href="#" class="btn btn-primary linkUpload" >' +'Yükle' + "</button>";

this.$dialog = ui.dialog({
    title: 'Döküman Yükle',
    body: j,
    footer: k
}).render().appendTo($container);
```

When the button is clicked, I try to get the values of the inputs:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var fileName = $("#mediatitle").val();
var totalFiles = $("#FileUpload").files.length;

for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];
    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
}
```

`totalfiles` returns 0.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `change` event to get user selected files at `<input type="file">` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
```

`$("#FileUpload")` is not the file input. It's a jQuery collection containing the file input. jQuery collections do not have `file` attributes. The raw DOM node does.

With a little cleanup:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var fileName = $("#mediatitle").val();
var fileInput = document.getElementById("FileUpload");
var totalFiles = fileInput.files.length;

for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = fileInput.files[i];
    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
}
```